# iOS - performance of filtering sets with a predicate

Tags: ios, performance, nspredicate, nsset

I am getting a UI stutter/pause on some older devices (ipod touch 4th gen for example), and I've narrowed it down to this piece of code:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"gender != %@ && catId != %@", [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], [NSNumber numberWithInt:7]];
NSSet *filteredCats = [cats filteredSetUsingPredicate:predicate]; //cats is an NSSet
```

If I comment out those two lines of code and do this instead:

```
NSSet *filteredCats = cats;
```

The performance is very smooth. So how can I improve this filtering without incurring the short pause in the screen updating?

Answer (score 2):

You can do your filtering asynchronously, which should help with performance:

```
 __weak ViewController *bSelf = self;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0ul),^{

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"gender != %@ && catId != %@", [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], [NSNumber numberWithInt:7]];

    NSSet *filteredCats = [cats filteredSetUsingPredicate:predicate]; 

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
        [bSelf updateMyViewWithFilteredSet:filteredCats]; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to let you know that you used dispatch_sync on the main queue..it can generates a deadlock.